# ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, 0, 0) - function in a Tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

Here's the error code :

```
Traceaback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programmes\PyCharm Edu 2022.2.2\projects\mdp.py", line 115, in <module>
    gen = Button(tabUser, text="Générer", fg="white", bg="#006400", font=("",15), command=generationMdp(longMdp, listeMain))
  File "D:\Programmes\PyCharm Edu 2022.2.2\projects\mdp.py", line 39, in generationMdp
    k = randint(0, o)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\random.py", line 248, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\random.py", line 226, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, 0, 0)
```

Function :

```
def generationMdp(longMdp, listeM):
    gene = ""
    for i in range(0, longMdp+1):
        o = len(listeM)-1
        k = randint(0, o)
        gene = gene + str(listeM[k])
        del listeM[k]
    return gene
```

Button :

```
gen = Button(tabUser, text="Générer", fg="white", bg="#006400", font=("", 15), command=generationMdp(longMdp, listeMain))
```

My goal is to run the "generationMdp" function every time the button "gen" is clicked.

I tried to see if the issue came from the function itself but it ended up working fine on its own so I think the issue comes from the code in the button but I cannot find where.

Comment: The `listeM` parameter (coming from `listeMain`) is apparently empty, so you're trying to pick a random number from an empty range.  This isn't surprising, since you're removing an element from this list on each iteration of your loop.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried putting test numbers in there too and it still wouldn't work. 

I remove the elements because I wanted to use them once and it also worked fine when I tried it out of the button.

Comment: `command=generationMdp(longMdp, listeMain)` will immediately run `generationMdp(longMdp, listeMain)` and pass the result to the `command` option.

Answer (score -1):

> My goal is to run the "generationMdp" function every time the button
> "gen" is clicked.

The button's `command` has to point to a function (that gets run whenever you press this button):

```
def show_somr_mdp():
    print('listeMain has', len(listeMain), "elements, of which I'll get", longMdp+1)
    print( generationMdp(longMdp, listeMain) )

gen = Button(....., command=show_somr_mdp)
```

Currently, your code doesn't make sense: you assign the result of `generationMdp` to the button's `command`. And my guess is that you populate `listeMain` & `longMdp` *after* that line got executed, which probably means this function got an empty listeMain. But that's just a guess.

As for `generationMdp`: as @jasonharper pointed out, it removes elements from `listeM` (and therefore `listeMain` too), and this is going to affect the next calls to this function (and likely lead to the error you see, sooner or later). To fix this, either send this function a copy of the list (`listeMain.copy()`), or have this copy made in the function, or (better) rewrite your code to use `random.sample()`.

At the least add `assert longMdp+1 <= len(listeM)` to that function.

Comment: So if I got this right, my problem is that I need to run a void function with generationMdp inside ? 
My goal with removing elements from listeM is because I want each element to only be used once and for each generation to be different, could this be avoided if I used a shuffle on the list and just went from 0 to len(listeM)-1 ?

I also tried making a copy of the list but the problem was still there, I will continue searching along with the new info I learned !

Comment: "my problem is that I need to run a void function with generationMdp inside?"

Yes. But I'm not too sure you got it right: It's not *us* who run the function; it's the button that runs it (whenever it gets clicked). So we hand the button (via `command`) only the name of the function. That's why my code has "command=show_somr_mdp", *not* "command=show_somr_mdp()". The missing "()" *is* the important thing. (You may see people using something called "lambda"; it's the same thing.)

As for removing elements from listeM: if it's intentional, then ok. But add `assert` to save yourself headache.

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot to reply to you, I managed to get it done in the end with the advices you gave me, thanks a lot !